# use dot to run a shell script why does "echo $0" print -bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

use dot to run a shell script why does "echo $0"  print -bash

Assuming I have a snippet of code below

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo $0
```

I execute using dot (.)

```
. ./script.sh
```

Output:

```
-bash
```

However,

if i run without dot

Output is the path name combined with the script name as I expected.

Answer (score 2):

Sourcing a script runs it in the existing interpreter instead of `exec`ing a new one, which means that `$0` is not initialized as normal.

Comment: Think of it as copy/pasting the code from the file you are sourcing. In that context, `#!/shebang` is just a comment, and there is nothing there which would modify `$0`.

Answer (score 0):

When you run a script with `.`, it's essentially as if you typed the contents of the script directly on your shell command line.  So `echo "$0"` will output exactly what it would output if you just typed it.

The special variables like `$0` are only initialized when you start up a new shell, which `.` doesn't do, or else it wouldn't be very useful.

However, if you're using bash version 3 or greater, you can always find out what file is currently being executed thus:

```
echo "$BASH_SOURCE"
```

which works no matter how the file is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

`.` is an alias for `source` :

Don't use this command for run a script, it has been created for import source files.
You can see that here : [Advanced Bash scripting guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html)

Comment: The ABS is only a mediocre resource. You should use `.` or `source` to run a script if you want to affect the current environment.